# Does the comma operator make the code slower?

Tags: c, comma-operator

I use the comma operator (in C) very often when solving problems on websites like *CodeForces*. and I've been noticing that my solutions seem to need more execution time than most of the other solutions, although there isn't much difference.

So my question is does the comma operator put more overhead on the CPU? like if the evaluation of its two operands isn't necessary. Would it be faster to separate them in two statements? Or the compiler would optimize it anyway?

Comment: Unlikely. But again, the only way to know for sure is to inspect assembly and/or profile. The language itself has no innate notion of "speed" for an operation.

Comment: `I use the comma operator (in C) very often` Don't. Write readable code.

Comment: If there is a difference, then it would most likely be variable based on the compiler, its settings and the platform it runs on. Regardless, I agree with @DeiDei that writing readable code should have a higher priority than, at best, micro optimisation. If you want optimisation, choose good algorithms instead.

Comment: @Dragonthougts why do you think its unlikely for the compiler to optimize it. I mean if the return value of the comma operator is never used, this would make a good optimization, I guess.
however, I started to convince that readable code isn't important in competitive coding as DeiDei said.

Comment: @OmarAlhelo I wasn't referencing competitive coding, but coding in general. Once you get away from competitive and you bring bad habits to real world projects, you're most likely to suffer. On the other hand I don't see "ugly" code performing better than readable code, especially the comma operator. Like Dragonthoughts said, good algorithms make performance, not commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The comma operator does not make code slower.

With that said, though, the comma operator is rare in most code.  Pretty much the only time you need it is when you're running a `for` loop over two variables, as in

```
for(i = 0, j = n; i < j; i++, j--)
```

(I believe there are C-like languages that permit the comma operator only in the first and third expressions of a `for` loop, disallowing it everywhere else.)

Any other time you're using a comma operator, it usually indicates you're doing something "clever" but unnecessary, which mainly serves to make your code more confusing or harder to read.

(With that said, though, it's also true that most of the commas in most C programs are not comma operators.  The commas separating the arguments in function calls are not comma operators, nor are the commas separating multiple declarations like `int i, j;`.)